# Replace duplicates with first values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
ITEM      CATEGORY       COLOR

48684      CAR           RED
54519      BIKE          BLACK
14582      CAR           BLACK
45685      JEEP          WHITE
23661      BIKE          BLUE
23226      BIKE          BLUE
54252      BIKE          BLACK
```

`df.loc[df.duplicated(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR','ITEM']), 'ITEM'] = 'ITEM'` Does not give me required output. I need the output a below.

```
ITEM      CATEGORY       COLOR

48684      CAR           RED
54519      BIKE          BLACK
14582      CAR           BLACK
45685      JEEP          WHITE
23661      BIKE          BLUE
23661      BIKE          BLUE
54519      BIKE          BLACK
```

If the `CATEGORY` and `COLOR` are the same replace the `ITEM` number should be replaced with the first value.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) by all values:

```
df['ITEM'] = df.groupby(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'])['ITEM'].transform('first')

print (df)
    ITEM CATEGORY  COLOR
0  48684      CAR    RED
1  54519     BIKE  BLACK
2  14582      CAR  BLACK
3  45685     JEEP  WHITE
4  23661     BIKE   BLUE
5  23661     BIKE   BLUE
6  54519     BIKE  BLACK
```

If want filter only duplicated for improve performance (if is more unique rows and less duplicates) add [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by 2 columns with `keep=False` and apply `groupby` only for filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), also assign to filtered column `ITEM`:

```
m = df.duplicated(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'ITEM'] = df[m].groupby(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'])['ITEM'].transform('first')
```